# Using Structure Map to replace an abstract type in generic type parameter

Tags: c#, generics, abstract-class, structuremap

I have the following class with a generic type parameter.

```
public class ContentService<T> : IContentService where T : DataString, new()
{       
    public ContentService(IEnvironment environment, 
                          ILogger logger)
    {
        _environment = environment;
        _logger = logger;
    }
...
}
```

DataString is an abstract class and I want Structure Map to use a concrete implementation (XmlDataString) whenever my application creates an instance of ContentService. Structure Map is already injecting concrete implementations of IEnvironment and ILogger when I do this:

Version 1:

```
_contentService = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<ContentService<DataString>>();
```

... but when I step through, ContentService is created with a type parameter of DataString, not XmlDataString. I have these three entries in web.config that set default instances:

- IEnvironment -> TestEnvironment
- ILogger -> Log4NetLogger
- DataString -> XmlDataString

The Structure Map site has [this](http://structuremap.net/structuremap/Generics.htm) to say about generics, but I can't seem to relate that example to my actual problem.

This approach works, but I'm losing the auto wiring of the constructor arguments and it looks quite ugly:
Version 2:

```
Type typeOfDataString = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<DataString>().GetType();
Type genericClass = typeof(ContentService<>);
Type constructedClass = genericClass.MakeGenericType(typeOfDataString);
_contentService = (IContentService)Activator.CreateInstance(constructedClass, 
            ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IEnvironment>(), 
            ObjectFactory.GetInstance<ILogger>());
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong in the first version, or how I might improve the second version?

Comment: What happens if you call `ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IContentService>()`? If that doesn't work, can't you add IContentService → ContentService<XmlDataString> to your web.config?

Comment: Thanks @svick, that works. I just inject the service as a whole. I was able to do that in code: 
`x.For<IContentService>().Use<ContentService<XmlDataString>>();`
but I haven't been able to find out how to put that in web.config (encoding the < & > doesn't work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, when you write `ObjectFactory.GetInstance<ContentService<DataString>>()`, you can't get `ContentService<XmlDataString>` back, because that's a different, incompatible type.

But it seems you actually want `IContentService`, so write that: `ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IContentService>()`. This will return the implementation of `IContentService` that you registered, so you should do that: register `ContentService<XmlDataString>` for `IContentService`. The fact that you have `XmlDataString` registered for `DataString` has nothing to do with this.

If you have problems representing the generic type `ContentService<XmlDataString>` in web.config, I think using the .Net representation of generic types (and not that of C#) should work. In your case, that would be something like `` ContentService`1[[XmlDataString]] ``, probably with added namespaces and possibly assemblies too.

Comment: I was trying to break up my dependencies and inject them separately, but I see that wasn't necessary now. Thanks for the answer!

Just in case anyone else gets stuck on representing generic types in web.config, here's what worked for me:

`<DefaultInstance
          PluginType="{namespace1}.IContentService, {assembly1}"
          PluggedType="{namespace2}.ContentService'1[[{namespace3}.XmlDataString, {assembly3}]], {assembly2}" />`